# Wave/Einstein Analytics & React App Communication

Tags: lightning, einstein-analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards

My gut instinct is to use [Analytics SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_sdk.meta/bi_dev_guide_sdk/bi_sdk_overview.htm), but a cursory glance doesn't reveal it.

Is it possible for Analytics Dashboards to embed *Lightning Components*, iFrames, or Connected Apps, or conversely for *Analytics Dashboards* to communicate information about the user's interaction out to a Lightning Component?

The use case is:

I have a React App that I have embedded in a [Lightning Container](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_overview.htm), but I want to be able to manipulate the React App based on the user's selection in an ***Analytics Dashboard***.

I know it's possible to trigger elements **within a dashboard to interact with one another**, and when the dashboard is embedded on a page, filter the results based on the lightning page it's embedded in, but curious if there is an API to react (no pun intended) to user's interactions in the dashboard?

**Update**

Functionally the Analytics SDK (Linked above) is nearly what I need, and I may be still discovering.

More specifically the [SelectionChanged Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_sdk.meta/bi_dev_guide_sdk/bi_sdk_web_example2.htm) can capture information when the selection is "changed" from within an Analytics Dashboard. That being said after I have attached the event and set it to *listen* for this event being fired from a dashboard I created, it only seems to fire ***when I change dashboard lenses that contain different steps***

Ideally, I would like to be able to manipulate the dashboard, have a "Table Mode" representation of the data, and *when a row is selected in that table* I can capture the data from that "table row":

Flow Chart:

[image: einstein-analytics-web-sdk+lightning-container-msg-poc-flow]

Starting bounty for:

1. Source Code or explanation/demonstration: capturing of ***Dashboard Lens Table Mode row-data after clicking*** in Analytics Web SDK SelectionChanged Event. This is Step 1/2 in Flow-chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not an expert in Einstein Analytics and the answer below is based on my limited experience while doing Trailhead on this topic and further test related to this question.

I have also posted [**this idea**](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lOdeQAE) based on the findings below to allow the event to be triggered based on row selection instead of selecting a cell of Measure column type.

---

Based on a test, it seems that the [`wave:selectionChanged`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_sdk.meta/bi_dev_guide_sdk/bi_sdk_web_example2.htm) is triggered from a table only when you have a [Measure dataset field](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_integrate_datasets.htm&type=5) added as a Column to the Table and that you select that particular *cell* in the Table. It does not respond to any other column added in the table. So as long as you have a Measure field, you will be able to listen to the `wave:selectionChanged` event.

Once I added the Analytics Dashboard to a Lightning App page and added the Aura Component (the code for the listener is same as found on the [documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_sdk.meta/bi_dev_guide_sdk/bi_sdk_web_example2.htm)) to listen to the events on the page, I was able to handle the event and get the values from that particular row from the Table.

Below is the sequence of screenshots as how I was able to listen to the event from a sample dashboard which had a chart and table components added to it. In my test, the Measure fields added to the Table were `Sum of Amount` and `Count of Rows` and selecting any cell value for these two columns fired the event.

[image]

Comment: Great find @Jayant Das! The array of data that is passed is exactly what I need, though it is certainly _strange_ IMOP that it would only be triggered when selecting a Measure Column, and the "Group By" columns you have to use to display other row data (dimensions) are kind of useless, at least in this context.

Comment: @jordan.baucke Glad that it provided you a direction. More than to be able to answer this, I definitely learned here. But you are right, I think that's odd that the event is triggered from a specific column and not others. I have opened an idea on this to allow this event to be triggered from a row selection independent of any column type. I have updated this in the answer for visibility.