# wave:selectionChanged behaviour in Summer '19

Tags: einstein-analytics, lightning-events

I'm creating a lightning app that interacts with an Einstein dashboard. The idea is that when a user filters data in the dashboard, a search is performed in an external system using the filtered data.

The big picture is not too different from the one presented in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256283/wave-einstein-analytics-react-app-communication/263195).

My components handle the `wave:selectionChanged` event to keep in sync with the selections made by the user.

Up to now (Spring '19), the `wave:selectionChanged` is fired by the dashboard when it's loading, allowing me to sync with the initial state of the dashboard.

Trying the exact same code in a Summer '19 preview org, I see that we're not getting the initial events when the dashboard is loaded. This means that my app is starting out of sync with the state of the dashboard, which means that the user now needs to do some workarounds for it to work.

- Is something that has been deliberately modified by Salesforce?
- Is it something that has been done under the hood?
- Is it a bug?
- Has anybody else experienced it?

Comment: If it was working fine with Spring '19 and not with Summer '19, I will definitely try reaching out to Salesforce support.

Comment: Already doing that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to post an update for anybody reading this.

I contacted Salesforce support and they confirmed that they remove those events at startup deliberately "to match documentation". After a lot of toing and froing, where we explained to them the impact it had in our organisation and our customers (and making them realize that their API offers no other way to achieve what we want), they have decided to reinstate the functionality back. The joys of premium partner support!